# Error code "AWT-EventQueue-0" and many more (WindowBuilder)

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, windowbuilder

In advance: I'm a beginner and my code might contain multiple fails, this is my 2nd time coding with a JFrame application and I don't get any visible errors before running, that's why I'm struggling to find the answer here. I believe all those or at least most of them refer to the same problem. I guess I'm missing something essential here(all those Unknown sources).

My Code:

```
package BWINF;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Aufgabe_3 extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField eingabe;
    private JTextField ausgabe;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Aufgabe_3 frame = new Aufgabe_3();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Aufgabe_3() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 431, 359);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 240, 240);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        eingabe = new JTextField();
        eingabe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        eingabe.setBounds(260, 73, 145, 20);
        contentPane.add(eingabe);
        eingabe.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblBitteGebenSie = new JLabel("Bitte geben sie ein,");
        lblBitteGebenSie.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblBitteGebenSie.setBounds(260, 11, 145, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblBitteGebenSie);

        JLabel lblWelcheDateiAusgelesen = new JLabel("welche Datei ausgelesen");
        lblWelcheDateiAusgelesen.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblWelcheDateiAusgelesen.setBounds(260, 27, 153, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblWelcheDateiAusgelesen);

        JLabel lblWerdenSoll = new JLabel("werden soll:");
        lblWerdenSoll.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblWerdenSoll.setBounds(260, 42, 108, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblWerdenSoll);

        JLabel lblDatei1 = new JLabel("");
        lblDatei1.setEnabled(true);
        lblDatei1.setVisible(false);
        lblDatei1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblDatei1.setBounds(132, 273, 266, 35);
        contentPane.add(lblDatei1);

        JLabel lblDatei2 = new JLabel("Datei konnte eingelesen werden!");
        lblDatei2.setEnabled(true);
        lblDatei2.setVisible(false);
        lblDatei2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblDatei2.setBounds(132, 283, 229, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDatei2);

        JLabel lblAnzahlDerDreiecke = new JLabel("Anzahl der Dreiecke:");
        lblAnzahlDerDreiecke.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblAnzahlDerDreiecke.setBounds(260, 126, 126, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAnzahlDerDreiecke);

        ausgabe = new JTextField();
        ausgabe.setEditable(false);
        ausgabe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        ausgabe.setBounds(260, 153, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(ausgabe);
        ausgabe.setColumns(10);

        JButton bBerechnen = new JButton("BERECHNEN");
        bBerechnen.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                Scanner sc1;
                try {
                    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
                    // User file lesen
                    String textnumber = eingabe.getText();
                    java.io.File textfile = new java.io.File(textnumber + ".txt");

                    if (textfile.exists() && textfile.canRead()) {
                        lblDatei2.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        lblDatei1.setVisible(true);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    sc1 = new java.util.Scanner(textfile, "UTF-8");

                    double readin[] = new double[100]; // NOCH FALSCH

                    int count = 0;
                    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
                        String text = sc1.nextLine();

                        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(text);
                        text.replaceAll(".", ",");
                        System.out.println(text);
                        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < readin.length; i++) {
                                readin[i] = sc2.nextDouble();
                                count++;
                                System.out.println(readin[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        sc2.close();
                    }
                    double endpoints[] = new double[count];
                    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                        readin[i] = endpoints[i];
                        System.out.println(endpoints[i]);
                    }

                    // DRAW LINE OPERATOR jeweils 4 stellen pro linie
                    for (int i = 0; i < (endpoints.length / 4); i = i + 4) {
                        g.drawLine((int) endpoints[i], (int) endpoints[i + 1], (int) endpoints[i + 2],
                                (int) endpoints[i + 3]);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        bBerechnen.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        bBerechnen.setBounds(270, 93, 128, 23);
        contentPane.add(bBerechnen);
    }
}
```

I don't really get what causes the Error so i posted my whole code here sorry if that's too much.

This is the Error im getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at BWINF.Aufgabe_3$2.mouseClicked(Aufgabe_3.java:141)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I reckon the error might be somewhere at the 2nd scanner(sc2).

Comment: `I reckon the error might be somewhere at...` - the error message tells you exactly where the problem is: "at BWINF.Aufgabe_3$2.mouseClicked(Aufgabe_3.java:141)". Line 141 is the problem.

Comment: Yeah that's where the second scanner is scanning the doubles :) i just dont know what is the problem right there and why the other errors occur or all errors occurring just because of this fault?

Comment: The message is telling you there is no "double" token to scan from the file. So your logic or data is wrong. You can't just assume there are 100 double values in the file.